# Why Does This Throw A Segmentation Fault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Why is this throwing a segmentation fault? I am debugging it and have narrowed it down to the assignment of the masses in the switch statement, how am I supposed to go about doing that instead?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 100


struct cg {
    int x, y, mass;
};
struct cg masses[MAX];

int numberOfEntries;

int readin(void) {
    FILE *file;
    int massesRead, i, num, partRead = 0;
    file = fopen( "WeightData.txt", "r" );
    if( file == NULL ) {
        printf( "Error: can't open file.\n" );
        return 1;
    } else {
        while( fscanf( file, "%d", &num ) > 0) {
            switch(partRead){
                case 0:
                    masses[i].x = num;
                    partRead++;
                    continue;
                case 1:
                    masses[i].y = num;
                    partRead++;
                    continue;
                case 2:
                    masses[i].mass = num;
                    massesRead++;
                    partRead = 0;
                    i++;
                    continue;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose( file );
    numberOfEntries = massesRead;
    return massesRead;
}

void computecg(int n_masses) {
    int sum_of_xmass;
    int sum_of_ymass;
    int sum_of_mass;
    for(int i=0; i< numberOfEntries; i++){
        sum_of_xmass += (masses[i].x * masses[i].mass);
        sum_of_ymass += (masses[i].y * masses[i].mass);
        sum_of_mass += (masses[i].mass);
    }
    int cg_x = sum_of_xmass / sum_of_mass;
    int cg_y = sum_of_ymass / sum_of_mass;

    printf("X = %d Y = %d.",cg_x, cg_y);
}

int main() {
    int number;
    if((number = readin()) > 0){
        computecg(number);
    }
    return numberOfEntries;
}
```

Comment: You placed your code, but you haven't explained what your code needs to do exactly. please read How to ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask And How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: this line: `void computecg(int n_masses) {` has the parameter 'n_masses', but that parameter is not used in the function.

Comment: this line: `while( fscanf( file, "%d", &num ) > 0) {` is not comparing to the correct value.  (see the man page for fscanf())  the line should be: `while( fscanf( file, "%d", &num ) == 1) {

Comment: in the 'switch()' cases,  1) end each case with 'break;' not 'continue;' and add a 'default' case for when the 'partread' is not 0 or 1 or 2

Comment: this kind of line: `masses[i].x = num;` is using an uninitialized variable 'i'    this kind of line: `massesRead++;` is using an uninitialized variable 'massesRead'.

Comment: the value returned by `main()` is a status, in general, 0 means success and any other value means a failure.

Comment: the same value is being declared/used by three different variables.  in the global file space: `numberOfEntries`.   in the function;`main()` `number`.  in function:  `computecq()`, the parameter n_masses.    Suggest eliminate `numberOfEntries`, and adjust the code accordingly.

Comment: for readability by us humans (and to correct a mis-understanding by the OP, as expressed in the line: `int massesRead, i, num, partRead = 0;` and the assumptions about the variables declared on that line:    only one statement per line, only one variable declaration per statement.

Comment: the loop that calls `fscanf()` needs to have a check that 'i' is less than `MAX` to avoid any overflow of the `masses[]` array

Answer (score 1):

You write things like this:

```
masses[i].x = num;
```

but after:

```
int massesRead, i, num, partRead = 0;
```

you never assign a value to `i`, so most likely it is some huge garbage number that is way higher than `100`, hence you go way out of bounds on your array and get your segfault.

You have a similar problem with never initializing `massesRead`, and then trying to do `massesRead++;`

To fix, you can change to:

```
int massesRead = 0, i = 0, num, partRead = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Very likely you assign more elements to masses than you defined. Print out your index i in the read routine and check, if it goes >100.